# AVPlayer for server live content not working without extension

Tags: authentication, swiftui, uikit, avplayer, iptv

Thanks for taking your time to help others.

### Problem description:

I would like to play LIVE content from server link, without an extension in native SwiftUI player. Server link follows this pattern:

> http://****flix.com:8080/username/password/channel

**I can't play an IPTV server link on SwiftUI**

### What I have checked?

Simple implementation of AVPlayer with link. (Not real data as involves credentials)

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let liveContentOK = URL(string: "https://ztnr.rtve.es/ztnr/1688877.m3u8")!
    let liveContentNotWorking = URL(string: "http://****flix.com:8080/username/password/channel")!

    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: liveContent))
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

- **I didn't forget** to allow arbitrary loads, as is the only way to handle http content.

As well, I tried on [this VLC implementation](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-ios), and it works with my IPTV link. BUT, the idea was to include this on a companies App so license is not valid. That's why I want to use something native, as AVPlayer.

[In this repo](https://gist.github.com/Fazzani/8f89546e188f8086a46073dc5d4e2928) you can find m3u8 links that currently works on AVPlayer too. But those are the easy ones, no authentication, has extension, etc.

Just in case, I also did tried to play the link appending .m3u8 and .ts extensions, with no result.

### A comparison working - not working

So, this link does NOT work: http://****flix.com:8080/username/password/channel

And this other link do work: https://ztnr.rtve.es/ztnr/1688877.m3u8

Differences I see?

- Is https (should be covered with arbitrary loads)
- Has an extension (I think that's not the problem)
- Non working link has a port 8080, that... I might handle?
- Has user authentication? Maybe that's the problem?

### Questions

1. Why is AVPlayer not able to play content? Do I have to handle decoding?
2. Is the port 8080 important? Should I attend that separately on AVPlayer?
3. Do I have to handle authentication? How?

Comment: Too many questions -- it runs the risk of getting closed as off-topic, but I'll answer a few in the comment here. 2) No 3) Yes -- it is already included in the URL 4) We don't know, since we don't know if the server requires authentication 5) Asking for library suggestions on SO is considered off-topic

Comment: Thanks for your help @jnpdx. You are right, too many questions and 1 off topic. Edited.